# registerTempTable not found

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am following a Spark example from here http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html.

```
val people = sc.textFile("../spark-training/simple-app/examples/src/main/resources/people.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(p => Person(p(0), p(1).trim.toInt))
people.registerTempTable("people")
```

I get the error that `registerTempTable` is not recognized.

After looking at some Github projects, it seems to me that I have the necessary imports:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Select people")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext._
```

And `build.sbt`:

```
name := "exercises"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.0.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.6.1"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You have another issue with the build file you've shared. It uses spark core 1.0 and 1.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, people is a RDD. `registerTempTable` is a dataframe api, not a RDD api. Your code drops the `toDF()' bit from the end of the example. Your first line should be as below

```
val people = sc.textFile("examples/src/main/resources/people.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(p => Person(p(0), p(1).trim.toInt)).toDF()
```